# Interaction between two sliders that update the same variable

Tags: dynamic

I'm basing this on the code found in the [*Introduction to Dynamics*](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html). I added one more slider which doesn't use the "round and snap" feature given in the link above:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0},
 Column@{Slider[
    Dynamic[x, 
     If[Abs[# - Round[#]] < 0.3, x = Round[x], x = #] &], {0, 5}]
   , Slider[Dynamic[x], {0, 5}]
   , Dynamic[x]
   }]
```

When sliding the second slider, I would have though the first one one stay snapped until `x > 0.3`, but that is not the case: the first slider moves together with the second one.

Is the update function **only** evaluating when the first slider is moved?

Comment: Yes. Each slider has its own update function that is applied only when that slider is moved.  However the positions of both sliders always track the value of `x`.

Comment: There is a bug in your posted code. The constraint function should be `If[Abs[# - Round[#]] < 0.3, x = Round[#], x = #] &`. Note the additional `#` in the 2nd arg to `If`.

Comment: Thanks, m_goldberg, for showing the bug!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've only set the update function to snap in the first, so it will always show the current value of `x` and only when you dynamically change it using *that* slider, will  the updating functionality be trickers causing it to snap. You can simply get what you are expecting by also including the snap functionality in the dynamically displayed value through:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0},
 Column@{Slider[
  Dynamic[If[Abs[x- Round[x]] < 0.3, Round[x], x], 
      If[Abs[# - Round[#]] < 0.3, x = Round[x], x = #] &], {0, 5}]
, Slider[Dynamic[x], {0, 5}]
, Dynamic[x]
}]
```